# Juniper MX device not responding

Tags: juniper-mx

Juniper MX-5. Power is on, lights are on, but device not responding. Console port not responding or displaying any output. Management port not accessible.

When you restart the device no output is displayed on the console port. The OK light does glow after a few minutes after startup as usual. Disconnected all ports and MICs and retried, but no luck.

I looked for troubleshooting guides and read forums to find ideas how I can attempt to test the device. Please advise on how I can do manual resets (using buttons on the device possibly) or other tests.

I just want to perform some tests myself before I send the device in for repairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to confirm that device is not dead to restart the router while connected to the console and check if there is any output coming and if it is not the router is dead.

Comment: Also need to check if console parameters are correct (speed, data bits) and turn off flow control.